# Trying to implement Render to Texture

Tags: c++, c, opengl, framebuffer, opengl-3

I'm having trouble implementing render to texture with OpenGL 3.

My issue is that after rendering to the frame buffer, it appears the rendered object becomes deformed, which may imply a bad transformation has occurred somewhere. Which doesn't make sense as the object renders fine when **not** using my frame buffer (see bottom of post).

**The current result is such:**

[Current result http://k.minus.com/jZVgUuLYRtapv.jpg](http://k.minus.com/jZVgUuLYRtapv.jpg)

**And the expected result was this (or something similar, this has just been GIMP'd):**
[Expected http://k.minus.com/jA5rLM8lmXQYL.jpg](http://k.minus.com/jA5rLM8lmXQYL.jpg)

It therefore implies that I'm doing something wrong in my frame buffer set up code, or elsewhere. But I can't see what.

---

The FBO is set up through the following function:

```
unsigned int fbo_id;
unsigned int depth_buffer;
int m_FBOWidth, m_FBOHeight;
unsigned int m_TextureID;

void initFBO() {
    m_FBOWidth = screen_width;
    m_FBOHeight = screen_height;

    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depth_buffer);
    glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth_buffer);
    glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, m_FBOWidth, m_FBOHeight);

    glGenTextures(1, &m_TextureID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_TextureID);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, m_FBOWidth, m_FBOHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glGenFramebuffers(1, &fbo_id);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo_id);

    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth_buffer);
    glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_TextureID, 0);

    assert(glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}
```

Here is my drawing box code, which just takes a transformation matrix and calls the appropriate functions. The current values of P is a projection matrix, and an identity matrix for the view matrix (V).

```
void drawBox(const Matrix4& M) {
    const Matrix4 MVP = M * V * P;

    if (boundshader) {
        glUniformMatrix4fv((*boundshader)("MVP"), 1, GL_FALSE, &MVP[0]);
    }

    glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(cube.polygon)/sizeof(cube.polygon[0]), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
}

void drawStaticBox() {
    Matrix4 M(1);
    translate(M, Vector3(0,0,-50));

    drawBox(M);
}

void drawRotatingBox() {
    Matrix4 M(1);
    rotate(M, rotation(Vector3(1, 0, 0), rotation_x));
    rotate(M, rotation(Vector3(0, 1, 0), rotation_y));
    rotate(M, rotation(Vector3(0, 0, 1), rotation_z));
    translate(M, Vector3(0,0,-50));

    drawBox(M);
}
```

And the display function called by GLUT.

```
void OnRender() {
    /////////////////////////////////////////
    // Render to FBO

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f,0);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo_id);
    glViewport(0, 0, m_FBOWidth, m_FBOHeight);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    GL_CHECK_ERRORS

    colorshader.Use();
    boundshader = &colorshader;

    drawRotatingBox();

    colorshader.UnUse();

    /////////////////////////////////////////
    // Render to Window

    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glViewport(0, 0, screen_width, screen_height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT| GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    GL_CHECK_ERRORS

    texshader.Use();
    boundshader = &texshader;

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_TextureID);
    drawStaticBox();

    texshader.UnUse();

    // Swap le buffers
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

---

And... the obligatory texture shader code

**vertex**

```
#version 330

in vec2 vUV;
in vec3 vVertex;
smooth out vec2 vTexCoord;

uniform mat4 MVP;
void main()
{
   vTexCoord = vUV;
   gl_Position = MVP*vec4(vVertex,1);
}
```

**fragment**

```
#version 330
smooth in vec2 vTexCoord;
out vec4 vFragColor;

uniform sampler2D textureMap;

void main(void)
{
   vFragColor = texture(textureMap, vTexCoord);
}
```

---

**The following is what is rendered when not using the FBO logic:**
[What is rendered to the FBO http://k.minus.com/jiP7kTOSLLvHk.jpg](http://k.minus.com/jiP7kTOSLLvHk.jpg)

---

... Help?

Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong?
Further source available on request.

Comment: Maybe your rendered buffer is OK, but the texture coordinates of the cube displaying the rendered buffer on its faces are wrong.

Comment: @Neodelphi, as was the case at the cross-post I made at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17554/trying-to-implement-render-to-texture. You're comment was correct. Thanks a heap.
Best make your comment an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was pointed out by [Jari Komppa on GameDev.stackexchange](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/17554/trying-to-implement-render-to-texture/17655#17655), and neodelphi as a comment on my main post.

The texture coordinates were wrong (or in my case, not passed).

Answer (score 3):

Without looking closely at your code, this is some example FBO code that works for sure (animates the Teapot to a texture, draws the texture to the sides of a spinning cube).

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

namespace render
{
    int width, height;
    float aspect;

    void init();
    void reshape(int width, int height);
    void display();

    int const fbo_width = 512;
    int const fbo_height = 512;

    GLuint fb, color, depth;
};

void idle();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH );

    glutCreateWindow("FBO test");
    glutDisplayFunc(render::display);
    glutReshapeFunc(render::reshape);
    glutIdleFunc(idle);

    glewInit();

    render::init();
    glutMainLoop();

    return 0;
}

void idle()
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void CHECK_FRAMEBUFFER_STATUS()
{                                                         
    GLenum status;
    status = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER); 
    switch(status) {
    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE:
        break;

    case GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED:
    /* choose different formats */
        break;

    default:
        /* programming error; will fail on all hardware */
        throw "Framebuffer Error";
    }
}

namespace render
{
    float const light_dir[]={1,1,1,0};
    float const light_color[]={1,0.95,0.9,1};

    void init()
    {
        glGenFramebuffers(1, &fb);
        glGenTextures(1, &color);
        glGenRenderbuffers(1, &depth);

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, color);
        glTexImage2D(   GL_TEXTURE_2D, 
                0, 
                GL_RGBA, 
                fbo_width, fbo_height,
                0, 
                GL_RGBA, 
                GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                NULL);

        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, color, 0);

        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth);
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24, fbo_width, fbo_height);
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, depth);

        CHECK_FRAMEBUFFER_STATUS();
    }

    void reshape(int width, int height)
    {
        render::width=width;
        render::height=height;
        aspect=float(width)/float(height);
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }

    void prepare()
    {
        static float a=0, b=0, c=0;

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fb);

        glViewport(0,0,fbo_width, fbo_height);

        glClearColor(1,1,1,0);
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(45, 1, 1, 10);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();

        glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
        glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_dir);
        glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_color);

        glTranslatef(0,0,-5);

        glRotatef(a, 1, 0, 0);
        glRotatef(b, 0, 1, 0);
        glRotatef(c, 0, 0, 1);

        glutSolidTeapot(0.75);

        a=fmod(a+0.1, 360.);
        b=fmod(b+0.5, 360.);
        c=fmod(c+0.25, 360.);
    }

    void final()
    {
        static float a=0, b=0, c=0;

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);

        glViewport(0,0, width, height);

        glClearColor(1.,1.,1.,0.);
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective(45, aspect, 1, 10);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslatef(0,0,-5);

        glRotatef(b, 0, 1, 0);

        b=fmod(b+0.5, 360.);

        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, color);

        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

        glEnable(GL_BLEND);
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);

        float cube[][5]=
        {
            {-1, -1, -1,  0,  0},
            { 1, -1, -1,  1,  0},
            { 1,  1, -1,  1,  1},
            {-1,  1, -1,  0,  1},

            {-1, -1,  1, -1,  0},
            { 1, -1,  1,  0,  0},
            { 1,  1,  1,  0,  1},
            {-1,  1,  1, -1,  1},
        };
        unsigned int faces[]=
        {
            0, 1, 2, 3,
            1, 5, 6, 2,
            5, 4, 7, 6,
            4, 0, 3, 7,
            3, 2, 6, 7,
            4, 5, 1, 0
        };

        glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 5*sizeof(float), &cube[0][0]);
        glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 5*sizeof(float), &cube[0][3]);

        glCullFace(GL_BACK);
        glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, faces);

        glCullFace(GL_FRONT);
        glDrawElements(GL_QUADS, 24, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, faces);

        glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

    }

    void display()
    {
        prepare();
        final();

        glutSwapBuffers();
    }
}
```

Just for reference to have something that works.

Comment: Cheers for this, it will definitely be something I'll have as a reference for later.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're multiplying by a matrix in the shader.  Assuming you're wanting to stretch the render-to-texture texture across the screen, you simply need to define 4 vertices, from -1 to 1 on x and y, and pass these into the shader (4 vertex if you're drawing a strip with 2 triangles of course).

In the shader just multiply the vertex by 0.5 and add 0.5 to get the texture coordinates.  So you don't need to pass texture coordinates in as you can generate these directly in the vertex shader.  The vertices are already in screen space if you define them as -1 to 1, so you don't need to do anything with them except emit them from the vertex shader.

Comment: The point was render to texture, not deferred rendering (which is what you seem to be hinting at).

Comment: I assumed the problem was rendering the rendered texture to the framebuffer after rendering to the texture :p.

Comment: Nah, I'm just waiting for neodelphi to write his comment as an answer. As that was the reason for the screw up.